# Phaser sliding puzzle random sort issue

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm using phaser sliding puzzle argorithm but i noticed the random sorting sometimes sorts unsolvable puzzle.

Someone explained below

[Difficult to solve the phaser sliding puzzle as some parts of the original image is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543163/difficult-to-solve-the-phaser-sliding-puzzle-as-some-parts-of-the-original-image)

but i don't understand how [5,3,4,2,6,1,8,7,9] get
5-3, 5-4, 5-2, 5-1, 3-2 3-1, 4-2 4-1, 2-1, 6-1, 8-7

I noticed that if i have this combination the 3x3 works
[8,6,0,2,3,5,4,7,1].

Answer (score 0):

It'sa me again ;) What I meant was the number of times that a higher value tile is before (in array; to the left of) a lower value tile. So count all pairs where a bigger number comes before a lower number.

For this algorithm to work though, it is important to count the gap tile (the empty tile) according to the goal solution of the puzzle. So if the gap/hole tile should go at the end (bottom right) then it should be the highest number. I suspect you are using incorrect numbering of this empty tile, are you using a `0` instead of a `9`? That depends on what the goal layout is.

```
Goal layout:
Correct   Incorrect
0 1 2     1 2 3
3 4 5     4 5 6
6 7 8     7 8 0
```

If the empty tile must go at at the end to solve the puzzle, then you should count it as the highest number tile, for example `9`.
From your example I'll assume the `0` is the tile that must go at the end, so last position in array. Then your example should be like this:

```
array = [8,6,9,2,3,5,4,7,1]

Count all pairs=
1: 8 is before 6
2: 8 is before 2
3: 8 is before 3
4: 8 is before 5
5: 8 is before 4
6: 8 is before 7
7: 8 is before 1
8: 6 is before 2
9: 6 is before 3
10: 6 is before 5
11: 6 is before 4
12: 6 is before 1
13: 9 is before 2
14: 9 is before 3
15: 9 is before 5
16: 9 is before 4
17: 9 is before 7
18: 9 is before 1
19: 2 is before 1
20: 3 is before 1
21: 5 is before 4
22: 5 is before 1
23: 4 is before 1
24: 7 is before 1
```

So 24 inversions needed in total, and 24 is even so it is solvable.